# How can I bind values that will survive in a PowerShell pipeline?

Tags: powershell

Coming from the simplicity of other scripting environments, I was surprised to find that the value of `$lookfor` was lost in the PowerShell pipeline: `Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Pattern' because it is null.`

That is, `$infiles` was usable as a value but `$lookfor` was lost in the pipeline. How can I fix this? I've looked at the PowerShell documentation and it is very confusing to this person used to Unix shells and environments.

```
$machine = "servername"
$lookfor = "magicstring"
$infiles = "*.conf,*.properties"
$user = "me"
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $machine -ScriptBlock {
    Get-ChildItem c:\some\path -Recurse -Include $infiles |
    Select-String -Pattern $lookfor -List |
    Select-Object Path
} -Credential $user
```

Comment: See `Get-Help about_Remote_Variables`. You want the section about using local variables. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_variables?view=powershell-7.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is not that it's a pipeline statement - the problem here is that the scriptblock passed to `Invoke-Command` represents a *serialization boundary* - before the code can run on the remote host, it must be serialized (converted to XML), transferred and de-serialized (turned back into executable code).

This also means that by the time the code actually gets to execute, it will no longer have access to variables in the calling scope - like your `$lookfoor` value.

There are two ways we can solve this problem:

### Parameterize the scriptblock

This is my preferred method:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $machine -ScriptBlock {
    param(
      [string]$Include,
      [string]$Pattern
    )
    Get-ChildItem c:\some\path -Recurse -Include $Include |
    Select-String -Pattern $Pattern -List |
    Select-Object Path
} -Credential $user -ArgumentList $infiles,$lookfor
```

Here, we declare the variable parts of the scriptblock as parameters, and then ask PowerShell to explicitly bind the arguments to it via `Invoke-Command`'s `-ArgumentList` parameter.

### Using the `using:` scope modifier

PowerShell also has a magic scope specifier that allows you to indicate that PowerShell should close over the local value of a variable in a remote script, like so:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $machine -ScriptBlock {
    Get-ChildItem c:\some\path -Recurse -Include $using:infiles |
    Select-String -Pattern $using:lookfor -List |
    Select-Object Path
} -Credential $user
```

Now, PowerShell will take note of the variables with the `using:` modifier inside the scriptblock when it parses the block, and as a result will know to bind the corresponding values in the calling scope to the variable references in the scriptblock.